# After the subscription is added to disposable in RxAndroid (Observable), the control flow ends without calling subscribe..!

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, dagger-2, rx-android

I am trying to use MVP, RX and Dagger 2 in android. The following is the code flow,

**LocalDataSource.java**

```
@Singleton
public class LocalDataSource implements DataSource {

@Override
public Observable getServerSettings() {
return mDBHelper.createQuery(ServerSettingsEntry.TABLE_NAME,
DbUtils.getSelectAllQuery(ServerSettingsEntry.TABLE_NAME))
.mapToOne(DbUtils::getServerSettings);
```

**Repository.java**

```
@Singleton
public class MyRepository implements DataSource {
@Override
    public Observable<ServerSettings> getServerSettings() {
        return mLocalDataSource.getServerSettings().compose(RxUtils.applySchedulers());
```

**LoginPresenter.java**

```
public class LoginPresenter implements LoginActivityContract.Presenter{
 @Override
    public void checkServerDbSynced() {
        mCompositeDisposable.clear();
        Disposable subscription = mRepository
                .getServerSettings()
                .doOnSubscribe(disposable -> {
                    Timber.d(" onSubscribe");
                    mView.showLoadingIndicator(true, "Checking Server ....");
                })
                .subscribe(serverSettings -> {
                            if (serverSettings == null) {
                                Timber.d("*** Server Db Synced ****" + "\n" + "*** Checking Licence Key **** ");
                                checkLicenceKey();
                                } else {
                                Timber.d("*** Server Db Not Synced *** " + " \n" + "*** Opening Login Dialog ****");
                                mView.showLoadingIndicator(false, "Db Not Synced ....");
                                mView.openLoginDialog();
                                }
                                },
                        throwable -> {
                            mView.showErrorMessage(throwable.getLocalizedMessage());
                            });
        mCompositeDisposable.add(subscription);
    }
}



    @Override
    public void subscribe() {
        checkServerDbSynced();
    }

    @Override
    public void unSubscribe() {
        mCompositeDisposable.clear();
    }
```

The problem is the statements inside subscribe is not being called. When debugging, I noticed that after this line *composite disposable.add(subscription)*;  the control flow ended…Kindly help …!!

**Edit**

```
public static ServerSettings getServerSettings(@NonNull Cursor cursor) {
ServerSettings s = new ServerSettings();
        s.setAndroidId("1234564453453463dfg");
                s.setDeviceId("tythyerju99");
                s.setIpAddress("6373792092.48949");
                s.setLicenceKey("fhfhdid");
                s.setExpiryDate("hshsh8ehd8");
                s.setId(2);
        Timber.d(" *** " +s.getExpiryDate()+" ****");
        return s;
    }
```

Comment: I suspect that `mCompositeDisposable.add(subscription);` returns false - is `mCompositeDisposable` already disposed?

Comment: @MarkKeen hi  ...no the composite disposable returns true...and i get subscriptions "0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `doOnSubscribe` executes the content on the same thread where `getServerSettings()` is executed which belongs to `Schedulers.io()`. Hence, your `mView.showLoadingIndicator(true, "Checking Server ....")` is trying to update the UI off the main thread (which is not allowed) and so this error terminates your `Observable` execution - you may see it in your `mView.showErrorMessage(throwable.getLocalizedMessage())` call but I don't know what exactly you're doing there.

What you should do is to send a message from your `doOnSubscribe` to the main thread as follows:

```
...
            .doOnSubscribe(disposable -> {
                Timber.d(" onSubscribe");
                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(() -> {
                    mView.showLoadingIndicator(true, "Checking Server ....");
                });
            })
...
```

**Update**

As it turned out after the discussion, the problem lied in `LocalDataSource` and `getServerSettings` method. Specifically, in usage of `mapToOne`. When a result set was empty then there was nothing to emit and that's why `subscribe` consumer methods were not called. To make sure that it doesn't happen, use `maptoOneOrDefault` that emits a specified default value if the result set is empty.

Comment: @Anatolli hi...the "mView.showLoadingIndicator(true, "Checking Server ....");" is being executed without adding the new Handler..the problem is that statements inside the ".subscribe()" of the observable is not executed..!! because i get the  progress bar loading!!

Comment: @robin1234 did you check on which thread the code inside `doOnSubscribe` is executed? From the code you provided it must non-UI thread so I don't get why it's working for you.

Comment: if i use  `if (Thread.currentThread() == Looper.getMainLooper().getThread())
    throw new IllegalStateException();`  inside the onSubscribe ...the error is thrown and caught in OnError method of the subscribe.

Comment: @robin1234 if you comment out `mView.showLoadingIndicator(true, "Checking Server ....")` will `onNext` inside `subscribe` be called?

Comment: No its not being called ...i guess the observable is not emitting any values..because on error throwable was called..I noticed that while debugging **DbUtils::getServerSettings** method is not executed ..!!

Comment: @Anotolii..i edited the post..the getServerSetting(Cursor cursor) ..is not being executed!!

Comment: @robin1234 Does `getServerSetting(Cursor cursor)` come from `DbUtils`?

Comment: @Anotelii...yes i do all the querying in the DBUtils  ie ; from Cursors to POJO.(ServerSettings etc..)..

Comment: @robin1234 could you add a log to here - `throwable -> Log.e("Robin", throwable.getMessage());`to tell us what error you're seeing there ?

Comment: @Anotelii hi....onError is not executed!! ...everything inside the subscribe method fails to execute ...and but if i throw a error like **if (Thread.currentThread() == Looper.getMainLooper().getThread()) throw new IllegalStateException();**  all the observable's method are triggered except onNext.

Comment: @robin1234 what will happen if `compose(RxUtils.applySchedulers())` is removed?

Comment: @Anotelii ..the same bug keeps occuring ..is it may be because the observables doesnt emit null values from the getServerSettings from the DbUtils class..

Comment: @robin1234 does `createQuery` or `getSelectAllQuery` get called?

Comment: @Anotelii yes they are called except the **DbUtils::getServerSettings** in the create query.

Comment: @robin1234 Are you using `limit 1` in your `getSelectAllQuery` query? Also, you should use `mapToOneOrDefault` as if the result set is empty you should fire something.

Comment: @Anotelli ..hi ..you are totally right!!...maptoOneOrDefault works...Observable has not been emitting because of  null values...thanks a lot for the help ;)

Comment: @robin1234 I'm happy it helped. I updated the answer with the latest findings :)